# Building a Camera Application... UIScrollView will not zoom

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I'm building a camera application, and I can't get the zooming on the image to work. I honestly don't know where to go from here, I'm sure it's some dumb mistake that I'm missing though. The app sets the chosenImageView to the workingImage (picture from the camera). When I try to zoom, nothing happens.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *workingImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *chosenImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *imageScroller;

-(IBAction)cameraButtonPressed;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.imageScroller.minimumZoomScale = 0.01f;
    self.imageScroller.maximumZoomScale = 6.0f;
    self.imageScroller.contentSize = self.imageScroller.frame.size;
    self.imageScroller.scrollEnabled = YES;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

}

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.chosenImageView;
}
```

[image: Hierarchy of my IB Items]

[image: Useless picture of the interface builder section with the UIScrollView/UIImageView]

Comment: What are the max and min zoom scales set to?

Comment: 0.01f/6.0f, my apologies

Comment: And you verified that your outlet `chosenImageView` is not nil?

Comment: Checked / set the `userInteractionEnabled` to YES on both the scroll view and the image view (probably the image view is the issue as it is set to NO by default)

Comment: I turned them on, but it still doesn't work. I also tried setting the multi touch to enabled on the UIImageView as well.

Comment: Where do you set the delegate on the scrollView . In the nib? . Without that connection you won't zoom

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I figured out what you meant, thanks! That worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the problem. You have to control+drag from the UIScrollView to the View Controller to set the delegate.

[image: Setting the delegate in interface builder]